# Create a button to open app from flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I would like to create an app in Flutter. The `web` version contains a button that should open version of `android` or `IOS` app according user platform if mobile version of app was installed (like an app install or open banner).

How should I detect `is app installed` in `web flutter`?

update:

I tried below code using `import 'package:universal_html/html.dart'` pakage:

```
window.location.href = (defaultTargetPlatform ==
                      TargetPlatform.android)
                  ? 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.mShop.android.shopping'
                  : 'https://apps.apple.com/us/app/amazon-shopping/id297606951';
```

But this just open the store. I'm looking for a solution to open app directly if it was installed.

Comment: Have you find any solution .?. Basically you want to deeplink your web with mobile app... I want to do the same opening app from web .. tell me if you find any solution yet

Comment: @ArslanKaleem No, unfortunately I have not found any solutions yet.

Comment: what basically is you want to open the app from flutter web and if app is not there then you want to redirect to appstore ???

Comment: @ArslanKaleem Yes, exactly!

Answer (score 1):

If this is fine for you, you can use an URL launcher. This way it opens the App store or play store and the user can either download the App or open it.

For Example flutter has a package that does most of this work:
https://github.com/Purus/launch_review

```
LaunchReview.launch(androidAppId: "yourpackagename", iOSAppId: "appid");
```

You just need to pass your package name and on ios your app ID

You could also use an URL Launcher:

https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

The code would be similar to this:

```
_launchURL(String url) async {
   if (await canLaunch(url)) {
       await launch(url);
      } 
      else {
        throw 'Could not launch $url';
      }
    }
```

URL Example

```
try {
  launch("market://details?id=" + appPackageName);
} on PlatformException catch(e) {
    launch("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName);        
} finally {
  launch("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName);        
}
```

Note this code needs to be adapted

Also see this tutorial for help: https://flutteragency.com/open-appstore-playstore-url-in-flutter/

**Edit:**

If you want to directly open another app you can use something like this:

https://pub.dev/packages/external_app_launcher/

> flutter pub add external_app_launcher

The Code would look like this then:

```
 await LaunchApp.openApp(
       androidPackageName: 'net.pulsesecure.pulsesecure',
       iosUrlScheme: 'pulsesecure://',
       appStoreLink: 'itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pulse secure/id945832041',// openStore: false
       );

                // Enter the package name of the App you want to open and for iOS add the URLscheme to the Info.plist file.
                // The `openStore` argument decides whether the app redirects to PlayStore or AppStore.
                // For testing purpose you can enter com.instagram.android
```

More infos regarding implementation and additional setup infos you can find here: https://pub.dev/packages/external_app_launcher in the Readme

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried it before using this pakage: import 'package:universal_html/html.dart'. But I am searching for a solution to open the app directly if it was installed.

Comment: Hello, I updated my answer to allow that

Comment: Oh excuse me I saw you want to use that for flutter web. Then this package wont work

Comment: Unfortunately yes, that doesn't work for flutter web.